# Как получить чистую консоль при запуске Spring Boot приложения?

Tags: java, spring-boot

При загрузке Spring Boot приложения в консоль выводится следующее сообщение:
[image: Фирменное консольное сообщение Spring Boot]

Как сделать чтобы при запуске приложения вообще не выводилось никаких сообщений в консоль?
Логи я убрал в файл.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Добавьте в `application.properties`:

```
spring.main.banner-mode=off
```